# MySQL query using GROUP BY is extremely slow

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

I have a database using the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sessions` (
  `starttime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
  `country_name` varchar(45) default '',
  `country_iso_code` varchar(2) default '',
  `org` varchar(128) default '',
  KEY (`ip`),
  KEY (`starttime`),
  KEY (`country_name`)
);
```

(The actual table contains more columns; I have included only the columns I query on.) The engine is InnoDB.

As you can see, there are 3 indices - on `ip`, `starttime`, and `country_name`.

The table is very large - it contains something like 1.5 million rows. I am running various queries on it, trying to extract a month's worth of information (for the month of August, 2018, in the examples below).

A query like this

```
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(starttime) as time_sec,
  country_iso_code AS metric,
  COUNT(country_iso_code) AS value
FROM
  sessions
WHERE
  starttime >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1533070800) AND
  starttime <= FROM_UNIXTIME(1535749199)
GROUP BY metric;
```

is rather slow but bearable (tens of seconds), despite that there is no index on `country_iso_code`.

(Ignore the first thing in the `SELECT`; I know that it doesn't seem to make sense, but it is required in the tool that uses the result from the query. Similarly, ignore the use of `FROM_UNIXTIME()` instead of a date string; this part of the query is generated automatically and I have no control over it.)

However, a query like this

```
SELECT
  country_name AS Country,
  COUNT(country_name) AS Attacks
FROM
  sessions
WHERE
  starttime >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1533070800) AND
  starttime <= FROM_UNIXTIME(1535749199)
GROUP BY Country;
```

is unbearably slow - I let it run for about half an hour and gave up without getting any results.

Results from `EXPLAIN`:

```
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys                      | key          | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sessions | NULL       | index | starttime,starttime_2,country_name | country_name | 138     | NULL | 14771687 |    35.81 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

What exactly is the problem? Should I index on something else? Perhaps a composite index on (`starttime`, `country_name`)? I've read [this guide](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) but perhaps I've misunderstood it?

Here are some other queries that are similarly slow and probably suffering from the same problem:

Query #2:

```
SELECT
  ip AS IP,
  COUNT(ip) AS Attacks
FROM
  sessions
WHERE
  starttime >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1533070800) AND
  starttime <= FROM_UNIXTIME(1535749199)
GROUP BY ip;
```

Results from `EXPLAIN`:

```
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+--------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys            | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+--------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sessions | NULL       | index | starttime,ip,starttime_2 | ip   | 47      | NULL | 14771780 |    35.81 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+--------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Query #3:

```
SELECT
  org AS Organization,
  COUNT(org) AS Attacks
FROM
  sessions
WHERE
  starttime >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1533070800) AND
  starttime <= FROM_UNIXTIME(1535749199)
GROUP BY Organization;
```

Results from `EXPLAIN`:

```
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys             | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sessions | NULL       | index | starttime,starttime_2,org | org  | 387     | NULL | 14771800 |    35.81 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Query #4:

```
SELECT
  ip AS IP,
  country_name AS Country,
  city_name AS City,
  org AS Organization,
  COUNT(ip) AS Attacks
FROM
  sessions
WHERE
  starttime >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1533070800) AND
  starttime <= FROM_UNIXTIME(1535749199)
GROUP BY ip;
```

Results from `EXPLAIN`:

```
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+--------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys            | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+--------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sessions | NULL       | index | starttime,ip,starttime_2 | ip   | 47      | NULL | 14771914 |    35.81 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+--------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Most of your queries are logically invalid, because you are selecting non aggregate columns not mentioned in the `GROUP BY` clause.  That being said, aggregation takes time, and slowness is to be expected, assuming your tables are fairly large.

Comment: First step is to get the query plan with `EXPLAIN` and see what’s happening there. Please include that also.

Comment: You have not provided enough information for us to help you. Please [read this note about asking good SQL questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/), and pay attention to the section on query performance. Then please [edit] your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I'm afraid I don't understand. I am definitely selecting (and counting) what is mentioned in the `GROUP BY` clause.
@SamiKuhmonen, I've edited the question to add the results from `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, queries of the form

```
  SELECT column, COUNT(column)
    FROM tbl
   WHERE datestamp >= a AND datestamp <= b
   GROUP BY column
```

perform best when the table has a compound index on `(datestamp, column)`. Why? They can be satisfied by an *index scan* rather than needing to read all the rows of the table.

In other words, the first relevant row for the query can be located by random-accessing the index (to the first value of the datestamp).  Then, MySQL can read the index sequentially and count the various values in the `column` until it hits the last relevant row. There's no  need to read the actual table; the query is satisfied from the index alone. That makes it faster.

```
UPDATE TABLE tbl ADD INDEX date_col (datestamp, column);
```

creates the index for you.

Beware two things.  One: single column indexes don't necessarily help aggregate query performance.

Two: It's hard to guess the right index to use to get an index scan without seeing the whole query. Simplified queries often lead to oversimplified indexes.

Comment: 1) From the guide about optimizing queries that I referred to in my message, I got the impression that you're supposed to use such a compound index only if the `WHERE` clause contained '=' comparisons. I'll try creating a compound index and see what happens.
2) These _are_ the complete queries. It's only the database schema that's simplified.

Comment: OK, I've created compound indices and the queries are much faster now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Even better...

Note that you do not have a `PRIMARY KEY`; that is naughty.  Having a PK won't intrinsically improve performance, but having the PK *start with* `starttime` will.  Let's do this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sessions` (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   -- note
  `starttime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(39) NOT NULL CHARACTER SET ascii default '',  -- note
  `country_name` varchar(45) default '',
  `country_iso_code` char(2) CHARACTER SET ascii  default '',  -- note
  `org` varchar(128) default '',
  PRIMARY KEY(starttime, id)  -- in this order
  INDEX(id)                   -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
  -- The rest are unnecessary for the queries in question:
  KEY (`ip`),
  KEY (`starttime`),
  KEY (`country_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;        -- just in case you are accidentally getting MyISAM
```

Why?  This will take advantage of the "clustering" of the PK with the data.  That way, only a section of the table that in in the time range will be scanned.  And there won't be bouncing between the index and the data.  And you won't need a lot of indexes to efficiently do all the cases.

IPv6 needs up to 39 bytes.  Note that `VARCHAR` will not let you do any range (CDR) tests.  I can discuss that further you like.

Comment: your solution ended up working faster than force index on the timestamp column. And yes, the order in the composite key did matter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(u1.user_id), u1.*
FROM
    table_users u1
WHERE
    u1.last_update_date = (SELECT MAX(u2.last_update_date)
        FROM table_users u2
        WHERE u2.user_id = u1.user_id);
```